# Entity Framework: Update Records with Include in Net Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I update Tables with includes in Entity Framework Core? The following seems to update the Customer Transaction, but Not Product Id.

Both Customer and Product have attributes which changes,  but CustomerId and ProductId stay same.

```
public void ModifyTransaction(IEnumerable<CustomerTransaction> customerTransactionList)
{
    foreach (var modifyItem in customerTransactionList)
    {
        var existingItem = _dbContext.Set<CustomerTransaction>().Include(x => x.Product)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerTransactionId == modifyItem.CustomerTransactionId );

        if (existingItem == null)
        {
            _dbContext.Add(existingItem );
        }
        else
        {
            _dbContext.Entry(existingItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

using Net Core 3.1

Comment: You haven't made any changes to the entity. What needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is prone to errors that will creep up depending on the scenario. When passing entity classes between client and server it is important to understand that the objects passed back to the server are merely serialized copies, not tracked entities. Because of the way serialization works, where a DbContext fetching two Transaction records that both reference a Product with ID: 14 would reference the same entity instance, that same pair of transactions, when deserialized, would have two separate object references, each with a Product ID: 14.

Given your example, at a minimum you would need to do something like:

```
foreach (var modifyItem in customerTransactionList)
{
    var existingItem = _dbContext.CustomerTransactions
         .Include(x => x.Product)
         .SingleOrDefault(x => x.CustomerTransactionId == modifyItem.CustomerTransactionId );
    var trackedProduct = _dbContext.Products.Local(x => x.ProductId == modifyItem.Product.ProductId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (trackedProduct != null)
       modifyItem.Product = trackedProduct;
    else
       _dbContext.Products.Attach(modifyItem.Product);
    
    if (existingItem == null)
        _dbContext.Add(modifyItem);
    else
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(existingItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(modifyItem);
        if(existingItem.Product.ProductId != modifyItem.Product.ProductId)
            existingItem.Product = modifyItem.Product; // tracked reference.
    }
}
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

}

What this amounts to is checking for an existing transaction like you were doing. However, we also have to check for any *cached* copies of related entities (Product) that the DbContext may be tracking. If we don't and we try to add a transaction that has a Product with an ID matching one the Context is already tracking we will either get a PK violation or a duplicate Product record with a new Product ID created, depending on how your Product PK is configured. (I.e. `DatabaseGenerated.Identity` column) We update the Product reference with a local cache instance if one is found, otherwise we tell the DbContext to start tracking the product instance. This assumes that this method cannot accept ***new*** products as part of this call, and that the Product record received should legally exist. Handling new products and validating the product passed in would require additional conditional code and DB checks.  From there we determine whether the Transaction is an update or an insert. In the case of an Update we can use `CurrentValues.SetValues` to copy across values, (as above) or Automapper, or manually copy the relevant values across. Assuming it's possible that a transaction could change the product, we also check the Product ID against the modified one, and if it's different we update the Product reference. `modifyItem.Product` at this point will be pointing to the DbContext tracked reference.

Updating entities with methods like this can be quite involved since you have to account for not only detecting new vs. existing records but potentially updating references to entities that the DbContext is already tracking. My strong recommendation is to adopt view models for explicit Add vs Update operations and deal with operations as atomically as possible. I.e. rather than passing a collection of transactions that might contain updates or inserts to work through, make more granular calls for each singular type of change. (Simpler, faster operations and fewer places for mistakes to occur)